# Who's responsible for USB 3 drivers

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, motherboard

During the motherboard driver installation at a clean Windows install, I'm asked to install USB 3.0 drivers.

When I do install them, USB 3.0 works fine. Even when I then update from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

This time when I installed Windows anew, I skipped the installation of the USB 3.0 drivers.

Now I don't get my USB 3.0 slots to work properly. 
Windows doesn't recognize most devices.

Now after updating to Windows 10, Windows won't accept the same driver disk anymore so I can install those drivers.

On the MSI motherboard driver website, there are no USB 3.0 drivers offered, and they're obviously not included in the chipset drivers coming from Intel.

This led me to the simple question who's responsible for the USB 3.0 drivers at all.

They're built-in to my chassis, then they go in to the motherboard and from there I don't know.

Can anybody tell me who's responsible for delivering the USB 3.0 drivers so that I can go search there?

Comment: USB 3 drivers are built into Windows 8+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a USB port is located on a motherboard, or connected to directly through a cable (USB on chassis for example), then the chipset on the motherboard is responsible for the USB ports, and as such, you need to install the chipset drivers.

Most likely there are installers available on the motherboard homepage, but if there isn't, then the motherboard says: we use plug and play drivers that ship with Windows. Although the manufacturer is ultimately responsible for the drivers, it can be Windows too where things stop working. But it is up to the manufacturer to contact Microsoft in these cases.